# Sobolev Interpolation problem

Tags: sobolev-spaces

I was asked to prove
$$\|u\|_{W^{1,4}(\Omega)}\le C\|u\|_{W^{2,2}(\Omega)}^\theta\|u\|_{L^2(\Omega)}^{1-\theta}$$

here $\Omega\subset\mathbb R^2$

but I don't know where to start, is there something to do with the sobolev inequality?

I only know how to calculate the index: by scaling argument $\theta=3/4$.

Comment: What do you know about interpolation?

Comment: @gerw In Adam's "Sobolev Spaces" $\|u\|_{W^{j,p}}\le C\|u\|_{W^{m,p}}^\theta\|u\|_{L^p}^{1-\theta}$ when $j\le m$, but the index doesn't match here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First use the embedding of $H^1$ into some $L^p$, $p>4$. Then interpolate $L^p$-norms (H\"older inequality), then apply the result you mentioned:
$$
\|v\|_{L^p} \le c \|v\|_{H^1},
$$
$$
\|v\|_{L^4} \le \|v\|_{L^2}^\theta \|v\|_{L^p}^{1-\theta} \le  c \|v\|_{L^2}^\theta \|v\|_{H^1}^{1-\theta}
$$
Since you are dealing with 2-dimensional domain, this is true with $\theta=1/2$ (see Temam's book on Navier-Stokes).
Set $v:=\nabla u$.
Then we get
$$
\|\nabla u\|_{L^4} \le c \|u\|_{H^1}^\theta \|u\|_{H^2}^{1-\theta}
\le c \|u\|_{L^2}^{\theta'} \|u\|_{H^2}^{1-\theta'}
$$
where in the last step I used the interpolation inequality for Sobolev spaces you mentioned in the comment. As written in the question, $1-\theta'=3/4$.